# How to remove colors from Maven output permanently

Tags: maven, maven-3

The log levels in Maven Output for example `INFO, ERROR` are in colored font. How to remove the colors from Maven output permanently with settings.xml?

I know it can be done with `-Dstyle.color=never` everytime calling the command line (or with a wrapper) but I am looking for a way in settings.xml.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have an active profile in your `settings.xml`. There, you should be able to add a `<properties>` section (if it is not already there) and add to it:

```
<style.color>never</style.color>
```

Comment: This has no effect:
`    <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>Hans</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
    <properties>
          <style.color>never</style.color>
        </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>Hans</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>`